# Help! Tiny black eggs on thyme stem

Tags: vegetables, diseases, pests, herbs

I wonder if gardening gurus here can help? The thyme plant I bought from the garden centre has tiny little black dots all along the stems, though the leaves all look untouched and the plant seems generally fine, for now. No insects flying around that I could see, and it doesn’t look like a fungal thing based off the scant results from Google, as the leaves are unaffected. I think I saw one moving so I think it’s an insect of some sort. They don’t rinse off well under water like I expect aphid eggs would?

This isn’t happening on any other plants I have - I have a baby tomato plant and some cucumber seedlings in nearby containers (all plants indoors). Any ideas what these might be? Thanks very much for any ideas in advance!

[image: could they be aphids]